# Validad ingreso dato string python

Tags: python, string, validación, datos

Muy buenas, no encuentro la manera de validar si el ingreso de un string es una palabra ya que me acepta números, gracias al try me repite que tengo que ingresar un dato pero pasa al siguiente si le pongo cualquier numero y por ultimo, en ambos casos de "nombre" y "edad" al introducir el dato correcto siempre me muestra los except "introduce algo" (el cual no debería aparecer si le estoy introduciendo el dato correcto (?)) Muchas gracias y perdonen, estoy aprendiendo.

```
nombre = ""
    edad = 0
    while not nombre:
        try:
         nombre = str(input("Ingrese nombre: "))
        except:
         nombre = ""
        print("Introduce algo ")
    
while not edad:
    try:
     edad = int(input("Ingrese edad: "))
    except:
     edad= 0
    print("Introduce edad valida ")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La indentación es fundamental en Python.

Veamos la validación de nombre. El requerimiento es que nombre no sea un número. La forma de validar es ver si efectivamente lo podemos convertir a punto flotante usando `float`.

Si el nombre no es un entero o punto flotante, la conversión generara una excepción, lo que nos dice que el nombre es efectivamente no un número.

Guardamos lo ingresado en `nombre` antes de intentar convertirlo.

```
nombre = ""
edad = 0
while not nombre:
    try:
        nombre = input("Ingrese nombre: ")
        _ = float(nombre)
        print("Introduce algo ")
        nombre = ""
    except:
        pass
```

La edad sigue un tratamiento parecido: lo ingresamos, tratamos de convertirlo a entero, y si falla, repetimos:

```
while not edad:
    try:
        edad = int(input("Ingrese edad: "))
    except:
        print("Introduce edad valida ")
```

produce:

```
Ingrese nombre: 1
Introduce algo 
Ingrese nombre: 1.0
Introduce algo 
Ingrese nombre: abc123
Ingrese edad: a
Introduce edad valida 
Ingrese edad: 1.0
Introduce edad valida 
Ingrese edad: 10
```